# How to move one column in a matrix to the right?

Tags: matrices

How to move the '*' under the diagonal dots one column to the right?

```
\[
A=\left[\begin{array}{cccccccccccc}
    * & *& *&  & & & & & & & &\\
    * & *& *&  & & & & & & & &\\
    * & *& *& *&*& & & & & & &\\
      &  & *& *&*& & & & & & &\\
      &  & *& *&*& & & & & & &\\
      &  &  &  & &\ddots &  & & & & & \\
     & &  &  &  &*&* & * & *& & & \\
     & &  &  &  &*& *& *&*& & & \\
     & &  &  &  &*&* & * & *& & & \\
     & &  &  &  &*& *& *&*& *&* &* \\
     & &  &  &  & & & & * & *& * & * \\
     & &  &  &  & & & &* & * & * & * \\
     & &  &  &  & & & &* & * & * & *
\end{array}\right].
\]
```

Comment: add a `&` at the start of the row, and delete a `&`from the end

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just add another column just for the `\ddots`.  BTW, you don't need to pad all the `&`s to the right.  OTOH, if you don't load amsmath, some of the asterisks will disappear. `\null *` or `{*}` will work though.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\begin{document}

\[
A=\left[\begin{array}{ccccccccccccc}
    * & *& *&  & & & & & & & &\\
    * & *& *&  & & & & & & & &\\
    * & *& *& *&*& & & & & & &\\
      &  & *& *&*& & & & & & &\\
      &  & *& *&*& & & & & & &\\
      &  &  &  & &\ddots &  & & & & & \\
    & & &  &  &  &*&* & * & *& & & \\
    & & &  &  &  &*& *& *&*& & & \\
    & & &  &  &  &*&* & * & *& & & \\
    & & &  &  &  &*& *& *&*& *&* &* \\
    & & &  &  &  & & & & * & *& * & * \\
    & & &  &  &  & & & &* & * & * & * \\
    & & &  &  &  & & & &* & * & * & *
\end{array}\right].
\]
% nested arrays
\[
A=\left[\begin{array}{ccc}
  \begin{array}{ccccc}
    * & *& * &\\
    * & *& * &\\
    * & *& *& *&*\\
      &  & *& *&*\\
      &  & *& *&*
  \end{array}\\
   &\ddots \\
   & & \begin{array}{ccccccc}
    *& *& *&* \\
    *&* & * & *\\
    *&* & * & *\\
    *& *& *&*& *&* &* \\
     & & & * & *& * & * \\
     & & &* & * & * & * \\
     & & &* & * & * & *
  \end{array}
\end{array}\right].
\]
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you so much.

Comment: +1. Since you load the `mathtools` package, you could further set `\setcounter{MaxMatrixCols}{13}` in the preamble, replace `\left[\begin{array}{ccccccccccccc}` with `begin{bmatrix}`, and replace `\end{array}\right]` with `\end{bmatrix}`.

Comment: I'd suggest `{*}` instead of `\null *`: here `*` is used as an ordinary symbol and not as a binary operation.

Comment: Of course, if you use `amsmath` there's no need for such tricks.

Answer (score 2):

It's simpler if you nest matrices.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}

\[
A=\begin{bmatrix}
  \begin{matrix}
  * & * & * &   &   \\
  * & * & * &   &   \\
  * & * & * & * & * \\
    &   & * & * & * \\
    &   & * & * & * \\
  \end{matrix}
  \\
  & \ddots \\
  &&
  \begin{matrix}
  * & * & * & * &   &   &   \\
  * & * & * & * &   &   &   \\
  * & * & * & * &   &   &   \\
  * & * & * & * & * & * & * \\
    &   &   & * & * & * & * \\
    &   &   & * & * & * & * \\
    &   &   & * & * & * & * \\
  \end{matrix}
\end{bmatrix}
\]

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

For a more general solution to the problem of inserting or moving columns in a table, you can use a powerful editor that lets you cut and paste rectangles.
With Emacs, you can start by aligning table columns to make rectangles. After selecting the part to be processed, you can activate the command

```
  `(align-regexp (mark)(point) "\\(\\s-*\\)\\(&\\|\\\\\\\\\\)" 1 1 t)`
```

Or by using the shortcut keys

```
   C-u M-x align-regexp RET \(&\|\\\\\)  RET RET RET y
```

Your table can now be modified by activating the rectangle selection mode

```
  `C-x SPC`
```

Then you can cut, paste rectangles or insert new ones by

```
 `M-x string-insert-rectangle`
```

Obviously, you should first learn some basics of using Emacs if you need it.